# This jQuery hide function just does not want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

Here's the HTML that my browser sees. I want to hide the `div.embed` element:

```
<div id="video_div">
<img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/ERF9lCf86I8/hqdefault.jpg" style="width: 200px; ">
<div class="embed">
<object width="300" height="194"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ERF9lCf86I8?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ERF9lCf86I8?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="194" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my application.js code to dynamically replace a link with its corresponding embedded video, display the thumbnail, and unsuccessfully hide the video:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
    $("#video_div").prepend($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 }));
});
$('div.embed').hide();
});
```

It's really weird that this hide method does not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to run fine here. -- http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/umQpw/

Comment: @Marcel: I'm still seeing the video (on Chrome on Linux).

Comment: doesn't work on safari either...

Comment: what!??! it works now for me! Maybe something was up with the embedly API?

Comment: and now it doesn't work again lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the code *above* the `hide` call is failing and the call isn't getting executed at all. If I put in a fake `embedly` plug-in, it works: http://jsbin.com/ucuru4/2

I recommend single-stepping through the code in a debugger. Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE8 all have built-in debuggers. There's Firebug for Firefox, and the free edition of VS.Net for debugging on previous versions of IE.

If the code is okay but you find that the `embedly` call is failing intermittently, may be best to wrap it in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: I'm really unsure how to do this. I ended up using a CSS attribute to hide the video, but now I'm implementing a simple jQuery click function to toggle the class and it doesn't work (while it works in other people's jfiddle hacks). I think there may be a fundamental mistake I'm making that no one can seem to figure out with just looking at code snippets. Would you please mind taking a quick look at my code? There's not much and it's a Ruby on Rails app.

Comment: @Justin: I'm not a Ruby person, I'm afraid. I really do think, though, that if you single-step through the client-side code in a debugger, you'll see what's going wrong. Using the debugger in Chrome is dead easy: Press Shift+Ctrl+I, navigate to the Scripts tab, find the `$('div.embed').hide();` line, and click the gutter to the left of it to put a breakpoint there.

Comment: shift ctrl l doesn't do anything for me :/

Comment: @Justin: In Chrome? It should. Alternately, try going to the Wrench menu, choosing **Tools**, and then **Developer Tools**.

Comment: hmmm... the script tab only seems to have my jquery file, my rails.js file, and my jquery-embedly API file that I include, but not the application.js file...

Comment: I did find this as a warning in the Console: `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.`

Comment: @Justin: *"the script tab only seems to have my jquery file, my rails.js file, and my jquery-embedly API file that I include, but not the application.js file"* Well *that* might be the problem. ;-)