# There's something really wrong with my simple Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Before people vote me down for not posting code snippets, let me tell you that I have tried this many times, but people cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. Check out [Why doesn't this jquery code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295370/why-doesnt-this-jquery-code-work) and [This jQuery hide function just does not want to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294799/this-jquery-hide-function-just-does-not-want-to-work) for examples of what is not working. It's a Ruby on Rails app using jQuery and the embedly API. The weird thing is that people have been copying the exact same javascript and html code into a jsfiddle and it works for them.

I'm asking if someone could please check out the code here and fork it: https://github.com/meltzerj/Dreamstill Someone who knows Ruby on Rails and jQuery well enough, and can figure out the embedly API. There's really not a lot of code at all, so it shouldn't be that much of a hassle. I would truly appreciate any help to get me on the right track. Thanks.

Oh, and please don't hesitate to ask me any questions.

Comment: before anything else, what browser are you using and have you tried any other browser?

Comment: yes, I've tried different browsers... my main browser is chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've pulled your code and I think (hope) I might have a solution for you, assuming I've correctly identified your issue.

I pasted a YouTube link in the form and was redirected to `/videos/1`, where there was a 'video' link, which was later replaced by embedly with the video's thumbnail.

The problem as I see it, is with this:

```
$("#video_div img").click(function() {
  $("div.embed").toggle();
});
```

When your document ready handler is called, there is no image in your document yet, so your `#video_div img` selector fails to find anything. This can be easily corrected by using the `live()` jQuery method, instead of `click()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/). I updated it to this:

```
$("#video_div img").live('click', function() {
  $(this).toggle();
  $("div.embed").toggle();
});
```

Which seemed to work fine: on click, the thumbnail disappeared and the embedded video appeared.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks!!! this works! i really appreciate it! Btw how is .live() different from .bind()? the docs weren't too clear on this.

Comment: `bind()` looks for your selector as soon as it is called, in this case `#video_div img`. On the other hand `live()` is regularly checking your document for the selector. If structure of your document is changing asynchronously, `live()` is probably the way to go.